# Get web traffic on port using http listener

Tags: c#, http

I have set up a web server using http listener. It is used to show a html file. The html file creates a request which I want the application to get. Here is a screenshot of the request in fiddler:
[This is the only request that needs to be captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpe3f.png)

This is what I tried:

```
var rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
Console.Write(ctx.Response.OutputStream);
```

This code always returns 'System.Net.HttpResponseStream' every time a request is made on the server. I want to see what it's returning but as a string.

Here is my web server code:

```
public class WebServer
{
private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

    public WebServer(IReadOnlyCollection<string> prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");
        }

        // URI prefixes are required eg: "http://localhost:8080/test/"
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("URI prefixes are required");
        }

        if (method == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("responder method required");
        }

        foreach (var s in prefixes)
        {
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        }

        _responderMethod = method;
        _listener.Start();
    }

    public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
       : this(prefixes, method)
    {
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                        try
                        {
                            if (ctx == null)
                            {
                                return;
                            }

                            var rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                            var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            // ignored
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            // always close the stream
                            if (ctx != null)
                            {
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        });

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
        _listener.Close();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: May be try this- Console.Write(buf);

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided it looks like you're writing `rstr` as a UTF8 string to the output stream, so when you read the output stream again to get what its returning you will get the same value as `rstr`. So doing this should print what you're sending back in the stdout/console.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(rstr);
```

or you can use the [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class to wrap the output stream and read the data as a string.

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(ctx.Response.OutputStream)
{
    // Seek to origin, to read all data in the output stream,
    ctx.Response.OutputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(content);

    // You might not want to close the output stream in case you want to do more work with it.
}
```

Comment: The first method just returns the full html file.

Comment: I can't get the second one working because of a lot of errors. It's because I'm doing it inside of a lot of things maybe. I will update my question with what I have